# Q: How to create ordered pair of strings

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, exception

I would like some guidance on a program I am working on currently, I have successfully created a pair of integers and handled exception if the user were to enter the same values twice. I am stuck on doing the same process of creating pairs but instead of ints it has to be strings.

One suggestion that I have is changing the random generation of ordered pairs with:

```
string empty = "";
myList2[i].setFirst(empty + char('a' + rand() % 26));
myList2[i].setSecond(empty + char('A' + rand() % 26));
```

Any suggestions in the right direction would be appreciated.

Client File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include "orderedpair.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cs_pairs;

int main() {

    int num1, num2;
    OrderedPair<int> myList[10];

    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
    cout << "default value: ";
    myList[0].print();
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myList[i].setFirst(rand() % 50);
        myList[i].setSecond(rand() % 50 + 50);
    }

    myList[2] = myList[0] + myList[1];

    if (myList[0] < myList[1]) {
        myList[0].print();
        cout << " is less than ";
        myList[1].print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myList[i].print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter two numbers to use in an OrderedPair.  Make sure they are different numbers: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    OrderedPair<int> x;

    /* use this before you've implemented the exception handling in the class:
    x.setFirst(num1);
    x.setSecond(num2);
     */

     /* use this after you've implemented the exception handling in the class: */
    try {
        x.setFirst(num1);
        x.setSecond(num2);

        /*if (x.setFirst(num1) == x.setSecond(num2))
        {
            throw OrderedPair<int>::DuplicateMemberError;
        } */

    }
    catch (OrderedPair<int>::DuplicateMemberError e) {
        cout << "YOU ENTERED TWO OF THE SAME VALUES!" << endl;
        x.setFirst(OrderedPair<int>::DEFAULT_VALUE);
        x.setSecond(OrderedPair<int>::DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }

    cout << "The resulting OrderedPair: ";
    x.print();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Header File:

```
#ifndef ORDEREDPAIR_H
#define ORDEREDPAIR_H


#include <iostream>

namespace cs_pairs
{
    template <class T>
    class OrderedPair
    {
    public:
        typedef std::size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;        // changed int to T
        static const int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;

        class DuplicateMemberError
        {

        };

        OrderedPair(T newFirst = DEFAULT_VALUE, T newSecond = DEFAULT_VALUE);

        void setFirst(T newFirst);

        void setSecond(T newSecond);

        T getFirst() const;
        T getSecond() const;

        OrderedPair<T> operator+(const OrderedPair<T>& right) const;

        bool operator<(const OrderedPair<T>& right) const;

        void print() const;

    private:
        T first;
        T second;
    };
}
#include "orderedpair.cpp"
#endif // !ORDEREDPAIR_H
```

Implementation File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

namespace cs_pairs
{
    template <class T>
    OrderedPair<T>::OrderedPair(T newFirst, T newSecond) {
        setFirst(newFirst);
        setSecond(newSecond);
    }

    template <class T>
    void OrderedPair<T>::setFirst(T newFirst) {
        if ((newFirst == second) && (newFirst != 0))
        {
            throw DuplicateMemberError();
        }
        first = newFirst;
    }

    template <class T>
    void OrderedPair<T>::setSecond(T newSecond) {
        if ((newSecond == first) && (newSecond != 0))
        {
            throw DuplicateMemberError();
        }
        second = newSecond;
    }

    template <class T>
    T OrderedPair<T>::getFirst() const {
        return first;
    }

    template <class T>
    T OrderedPair<T>::getSecond() const {
        return second;
    }

    template <class T>
    OrderedPair<T> OrderedPair<T>::operator+(const OrderedPair<T>& right) const {
        return OrderedPair(first + right.first, second + right.second);
    }

    template <class T>
    bool OrderedPair<T>::operator<(const OrderedPair<T>& right) const {
        return first + second < right.first + right.second;
    }

    template <class T>
    void OrderedPair<T>::print() const {
        std::cout << "(" << first << ", " << second << ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note: [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an ordered container that does not allow duplicates.

Comment: Don't `#include "orderedpair.cpp"`, change extension for one of .inl, .icc, hxx, ...

Answer (score 1):

To be generic, get rid of `static const int DEFAULT_VALUE = 0;`

Get rid of default constructor which doesn't respect your invariant

I would get rid of individual setter which might be problematic when uses together:

```
void swap_order(OrderedPair<int>& op)
{
    const auto first = op.getFirst();
    op.setFirst(op.getSecond()); // Oups... throw exception
    op.setSecond(first);
}
```

So:

```
template <class T>
class OrderedPair
{
public:
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using value_type = T;

    class DuplicateMemberError{};

    OrderedPair(const T& newFirst, const T& newSecond) : first(newFirst), second(newSecond) { check(); }

    const T& getFirst() const { return first; }
    const T& getSecond() const { return second; }

    OrderedPair<T> operator+(const OrderedPair<T>& right) const;
    bool operator<(const OrderedPair<T>& rhs) const;
    void print() const;

private:
    void check() { if (first == second) throw DuplicateMemberError{}; }
private:
    T first;
    T second;
};
```

As no longer default constructible, you have to change

`OrderedPair<int> myList[10];` by

```
std::vector<OrderedPair<int>> myList; /*myList.reserve(10);*/
```

and generation would be:

```
//const std::string empty;
const char lower_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // 'a'-'z' is not guaranty to be contiguous (EBCDIC)
const char upper_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // 'A'-'Z' is not guaranty to be contiguous (EBCDIC)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myList.emplace_back(rand() % 50, rand() % 50 + 50);
    // myList.emplace_back(empty + char(lower_alphabet[rand() % 26], empty + char(upper_alphabet[rand() % 26]);
}
```